# Display Mongoose find in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Being new to MongoDB and Mongoose, I feel really lost here.

After trying soooo many ways, I'm stuck with this: I can't figure out how Mongoose actually works, I went back to original state for clearer code reading, my tryouts are crashing node.JS.

I have this in the app.js that works:

```
PolyModel.find(null, function (err, poly) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  console.log(poly);
});
```

Console shows good results in the shell, using a nice JSON format.

This line sends everything to the router

```
app.use('/', index);
```

My router:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Polygon grid', author: 'Author'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

My main question is: how do I get this poly value in the router / views?

I've red so much stuff and would like to learn the proper practices.

For information, my final goal would be to get this value into an Angular ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use module.exports function to expose the PolyModel schema on your js file that has all the routes. After that you can use it just above the res.render to get your data and then in the callback of the query use the res.render

If you don't want to run the query inside the routes javascript file you could implement a small express router middleware . Here is the documentation for it: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router

Edit: Sadly I don't know how to use neither Jade template engine nor angular. I have only worked with EJS and jquery but I believe you can do something like this:

```
<script>
var something = #{poly};
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get it, I have a module exports in the app.js and index.js, but I don't understand what you mean by exposing the PolyModel schema

Comment: You will have to run the PolyModel.find() function just above the res.render like this:
PolyModel.find(null, function(err,poly){
res.render("use your poly")
}
So as you may understand you will need to load PolyModel in the file that you have the routes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you saved me many days! I feel really close now, I can display it with #{poly} in the view but still struggle to use it in my angular ng repeat

Comment: I don't know how to use this template engine but I believe you can do what I typed just now on my original answer